# Incomplete HDFS URI, no host, altohugh file does exist

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs, hdp

i'm trying to access via pyspark to my files in hdfs with the following code:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MongoDBIntegration").getOrCreate()
receipt = spark.read.json("hdfs:///bigdata/2.json")
```

and i get an error `Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:///bigdata/2.json`

but if i write the command `hdfs dfs -cat  /bigdata/1.json` it does print me my file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that you have not specified the host in the HDFS URI.

Try to change the URI with:

```
hdfs://<HDFS_HOST>:<HDFS_PORT>/bigdata/2.json
```

Comment: tried as hdfs://localhost:8020/bigdata/2.json and got an error:java.net.ConnectException: Call From sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com/172.18.0.2 to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;

Comment: you have to check which is the listen address of your HDFS NameNode (```fs.default.name```)

Comment: <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>

Comment: Try the URI ```hdfs://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:8020/bigdata/2.json```

Comment: it worked! but i don't understand, why with localhost it didn't worked? i checked my hosts file, there is a redirection from sandbox to localhost